# how to hibernate only one proccess in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, hibernation

how to hibernate only one proccess in ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to explain what you are trying to do, but [cryopid](http://cryopid.berlios.de/) might be what you are after.

Comment: i want to save proccess execution state to hdd the load it and continue execution

Answer (score 1):

If one wants to (just) "suspend" a current process can easily send a STOP signal:

```
kill -STOP id
```

Then resume later:

```
kill -CONT id
```

It will not survive a reboot and it is tied to a particular machine.